# For two unit non-oriented bivectors $A,B\in \mathbb{R}P^2\subset \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^3$ is the mapping $\phi:(A,B)\rightarrow AB$ bijective?

Tags: geometry, functions, proof-writing, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

For two non-oriented unit bivectors $A,B\in \mathbb{R}P^2\subset \Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^3$ is the mapping $\phi:\mathbb{R}P^2\times \mathbb{R}P^2/\mathbf{D} \rightarrow S^3$, where $\mathbf{D}$ is the diagonal $\{(x,x):x\in \mathbb{R}P^2\}$, of the form $\phi:(A,B)\rightarrow AB$ bijective? That is, is the mapping from two non-oriented ($A\sim -A,B\sim -B$) unit bivectors to their geometric product bijective, as long as the two bivectors are not the same? Intuitively this makes sense, but I'm having a hard time justifying it algebraically.

Comment: The map doesn't seem well-defined, since $(A,B)\mapsto AB$ but $(-A,B)\mapsto -AB$. Perhaps you quotiented by one too many $\Bbb Z_2$s. And I don't see how $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is naturally a subset of $\Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^3$. Anyway, would it be safe to say you want to know the fibers of the map $S^2\times S^2\to S^3\subset\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^3$ given by $(u,v)\mapsto (u\cdot v,u\times v)$?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that's a perfect contradiction to the map. I guess I was abusing the notation $\mathbb{R}P^2$, what I really meant was the set of bivectors $x\in\Lambda^2\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $|x|^2=1$ and $x\sim −x$. 

Although the particular geometric problem I am working on involves the quotient $\mathbf{D}$, knowing the fibers of the map $S^2\times S^2\rightarrow S^3\subset \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^3$ would be a tremendous help!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

An equivalent question is: what are the fibers of the map 
$$\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3, (v,w)\mapsto v\times w$$

Comment: I see what you're saying, the fiber of $u$ is the set of all vectors $(v,w)$ in the plane. The fiber of $\{1\}$ is the diagonal $\mathbf{D}=\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{R}P^2\}$ - I had forgotten to include this quotient in the original question, but now I've edited the question.

Comment: @AGentleRose: Don't you get the element $0$ by multiplying the proportional vectors?

Comment: $AB = A\cdot B + A\wedge B=A\cdot B=1$ when they're proportional.

Comment: @AGentleRose: Aha. Well, if two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are rotated together in the plane that they are forming, the wedge stays the same, and also the scalar product. All these rotated pairs give the same product. And conversely.

Comment: Hm, this seems to be where the distinction that $A,B$ are bivectors comes into play: the resulting geometric product has a scalar component and a bivector component. Just checked using the Python library "clifford": unless $R(AB)R^{-1}=AB$, which is true when the bivector component of $R$ is equivalent to the bivector component of $AB$, rotating the multivector results in a pseudoscalar component, which means $\nexists CD:CD=R(AB)R^{-1},AB\neq CD$.

Comment: Actually I realized that this is not true - if the rotor $R$ is in the plane $A*B$, then $(RAR^{-1})(RBR^{-1})=AB$. To encode pairs of bivectors like this I'll need to move into the conformal model for bivectors... well it was worth an attempt.